# Getting segmentation fault when allocating a linked list and assigning it values in c

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to create a singly linked list and initialize it with the first given n integers.But i am getting segmentation fault whenever i run it.This is my code.

```
 typedef struct floatList{float fval;struct floatList * fnext;}node_f;


 node_f* FL_firstInts(int n){

        node_f *res=(node_f*)malloc(sizeof(node_f));
        res=res->fnext;

        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            res->fval=i;
            res=res->fnext;
        }
        return res;
    }

void FL_show(struct floatList *list, char *label){
    int i=0;
    while(list->fnext!=NULL){
        printf("%d: %f\n",i,f->fval);           
        list=list->fnext;
        i++;
    }
}
```

And in order to test in the main function, i write the following

```
node_f *ten = FL_firstInts(10);
FL_show(ten,"10 first integers");
```

But as i run the program, i get segmentation fault,how do i fix it?

Comment: A segmentation fault means you're program is trying to access memory it isn't allowed to. This is usually a symptom of off by one errors or non-termination of loops.

In your case how does you `while` loop terminate? When are you setting `NULL` pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `FL_firstInts` you allocated uninitialized object of the type node_f

```
node_f *res=(node_f*)malloc(sizeof(node_f));
```

So the following statement

```
res=res->fnext;
```

already invokes undefined behavior.

The function can be defined at least the following way

```
node_f * FL_firstInts( int n )
{
    node_f *head = NULL;
    node_f **current = &head;
`
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        *current = malloc( sizeof( node_f ) );

        ( *current )->fval  = i;
        ( *current )->fnext = NULL;

        current = &( *current )->fnext;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Th function `FL_show` has the same bug and moreover the parameter `label` is not used.

The function can be defined like

```
void FL_show( const node_f *head, const char *label )
{
    if ( label ) puts( label );

    for ( int i = 0; list != NULL; list = list->fnext )
    {
        printf( "%d: %f\n", i, f->fval );           
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
node_f *res=(node_f*)malloc(sizeof(node_f));
res=res->fnext;
```

The reason for your crash is that you're never initialising the `res->fnext` pointer.
So before accessing it set it to the actual next element in your list.

In general your code is a bit fuzzy.
You're allocating memory for *one* `node_f`, but you're actually trying to put `n` elements into it.

To allocate memory for the `n` elements just multiply the size of one element by `n`.

```
node_f *res= (node_f*) malloc(sizeof(node_f) * n);
```

Afterwards initialise the `fnext` pointers.

```
for(size_t index{0}; index < n - 1; index++)
  res[index].fnext = &res[index + 1];
res[n - 1].fnext = nullptr;
```